# REST call to save large ResultSet to downloadable CSV

Tags: java, rest, csv, jdbc, resultset

I am creating a REST service that loads data from Oracle database table using JDBC, and saves the `resultset` in CSV.

Since the table is very large, it's expected that the process will take about one hour.

How can I download CSV **while** saving data to it
(so we get a cycle like this: **load chunk** (some amount of rows), **save to CSV**, and **flush** that part (download) )?

this is intended to:

1. prevent holding the whole file in server memory, by flushing it periodically to the client.(**Assuming** JDBC driver does not fetch all table immediately)
2. show (almost) immediate progress to the user (so user won't wait until CSV is complete)

Answer (score -1):

something like this is good enough:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/csv")
@Path("/get")
public Response getData(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                               @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {


    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=data_file.csv");

    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    // here you read from ResultSet. 
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        byte b = (byte) (resultSet.getByte("columnA"));
        outputStream.write(b);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: What is `i` at `array[i]`?

Comment: array is just an example of data container that holds data. this contradicts the whole idea of not holding all data in memory. so it should be replaced with `outputStream.write(int b)`

Comment: So, this only gets one column?

Comment: yup. again. just an example. all I wanted to show is the use of OutputStream with resultSet